# Store object that has a List of objects as a property, without these objects generating a seperate table

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this class that has 2 complex properties:

```
public class App
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string StringId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string AppName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Guid WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    public List<FieldStructure> Fields { get; set; } = new List<FieldStructure>();
    public List<FieldStructureRelation> RelationFields { get; set; } = new List<FieldStructureRelation>();
}
```

These are said properties objects:

```
[Owned]
public class FieldStructure
{
    public FieldStructure(string name, string type)
    {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
            NameAsProperty = name.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_");
            
    }

    public FieldStructure() { }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NameAsProperty { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;

}
[Owned]
public class FieldStructureRelation : FieldStructure
{
    public FieldStructureRelation(FieldStructure fieldStructure, string appRelationId) 
        : base(fieldStructure.Name, fieldStructure.Type)
    {
        this.AppRelationId = appRelationId;
    }

    public FieldStructureRelation(string name, string type, string appRelationId) 
        : base(name, type) 
    {
        this.AppRelationId = appRelationId;
    }
        
    public FieldStructureRelation() { }

    public string AppRelationId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

All I want is to store these properties in my Apps tables in columns, not in separate tables... maybe as a JSON object?

I thought that doing this in my dbcontext would be enough, but no, it keeps generating tables and not showing the properties in my apps:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<App>()
    .OwnsMany(app => app.Fields, fields =>
    {
        fields.Property(c => c.Type);
        fields.Property(c => c.Name);
        fields.Property(c => c.NameAsProperty);
    });
modelBuilder.Entity<App>()
    .OwnsMany(app => app.RelationFields, rFields =>
    {
        rFields.Property(c => c.Type);
        rFields.Property(c => c.Name);
        rFields.Property(c => c.NameAsProperty);
        rFields.Property(c => c.AppRelationId);
    });
```

I feel like this should be a pretty easy straight forward thing to do but I can't see the right way of doing it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try ICollection instead of List

Comment: @Monofuse same thing happens... et even generates an Id field in their tables for some reason

Comment: Imagine you need to generate table (if you want to store it as one table) for this class. How many columns should be generated for `FieldStructure.Name`? One? Two? One million? There is no way to tell how many elements will be in the list.